# Configure wildcard certificates with traefik and let's encrypt?

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik

Starting with traefik 1.6.0 it should be possible to get wildcard certificates from Let's Encrypt for a domain, using the dns challenge.

Using the example below, what do you need to change to get wildcard certificates?

```
# Enable ACME (Let's Encrypt): automatic SSL
[acme]
email = "test@traefik.io"
storage = "C:/etc/ssl/lets-encrypt.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging = true
  [acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"

  [[acme.domains]]
    main = "domain.com"
    sans = ["www.domain.com","sub.domain.com"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Change what you are looking for is implemented ~2-3 days ago in traefik and the documentation could be found @[traefik.io v1.6 acme](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/acme/)

from what you shared in the question, I see you are using CloudFare as provider and from the very same configuration link above, below configuration properties are to be included as well :--

> 1. **CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL**
> 2. **CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY** - The Cloudflare Global API Key
>      needs to be used and not the Origin CA Key

Add those config properties and try to generate WildCard?

Important points to consider:

> **Wildcard domains** Wildcard domain has to be defined as a main domain
>   with no SANs (alternative domains). All domains must have A/AAAA
>   records pointing to Træfik.
>
> > **WARNING** Note that Let's Encrypt has [rate limiting](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits).

Comment: So all the domains that you have dynamically defined must have A/AAAA records? Or just the main domain. And then I assume that traefik won't automatically update DNS to match anything?

Answer (score 3):

I got it working like this:

```
[acme]
email = "test@traefik.io"
storage = "C:/etc/ssl/lets-encrypt.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging = true
  [acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  [[acme.domains]]
    main = "*.domain.com"
    sans = ["domain.com"]
```

Thank you @Farhan for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

"For the moment, we do not support wildcard certificates with/in SANs."

https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/3063#issuecomment-376440741